# Jamon statistics aggregation across multiple JVMs

Tags: java, performance, jvm, monitoring, aggregation

I have a tomcat server running a webapp. Apart from this there are two other JVMs that run batch processing tasks. Jamon is a really cool way to monitor performance, hits etc., and can be viewed on the web using Jamonadmin.jsp (supplied with jamon war file). But I want to aggregate the Jamon statistics from the other two JVMs and display on the tomcat server VM.

I was thinking of a port on each of the two VMs that respond with serialized Jamon objects when asked from tomcat..

Is there any such feature already exisiting in Jamon API? or any recommendations to achieve this?

Thanks,
-Keshav

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for something similar and have just stumbled on this post:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/case-study-performance-tuning--0

JARep is a reporting tool for application performance data, extracted from a performance measuring tool like JAMon API. The data is then stored in a database. Via a webapp or a Swing application you can view the performance over time. Data can be aggregated across multiple JVMs.

Have not tried myself, but looks very promising!

Comment: Thanks for the info! Looks very close to what I am looking for :)

Comment: Keshav, have you tried it out? I'm looking facing the same challenge.

Comment: Hi user85155, just had a look, but never got a chance to try JARep.